# Illogical jsp error

Tags: java, jsp

I want to dispaly a result parameter which return from servlet to jsp after an event happen.
so when i add new user for example a result parameter  returns with value that the user has been added successfully , and i want to display the result in jsp page. 
i make like this in jsp page

```
<%String result = String.valueOf(request.getAttribute("result"));%>
 <%if (result != null){%>
 <%= result%>
<%}%>
```

**THE PROBLEM** is that every time i open the page for the first time result prints as null to the browser even i write if not null print result value, where is the problem ? can someone help/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.valueOf(..)` returns `"null"` (a `String` with length 4) if the argument is `null`. So your quick solution would be not to use `String.valueOf(..)` at all.

However, it is not advisable to use scriptlets and java code like that in your JSPs. Use JSTL and EL instead. Your code would look like this:

```
<c:if test="${result != null}">
    ${result}
</c:if>
```

Comment: it doesn't work even i make if(result.equals("null")){print result}

Comment: I advised for getting rid of the `String.valueOf(..)` completely. There is no point in comparing a string to the "null" string

Comment: many thanx , but why scriptlets  are not  advisable in jsp pages?

Comment: @Alaa - see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188706/how-to-avoid-using-scriptlets-in-my-jsp-page and BalusC's answer

Comment: Actually, it's this one :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files The OP was however told/linked that several times before in his previous questions.

Comment: @BalusC, ah, yes. :) I wondered where did all those upvotes go. Anyway, there are too many of these.