# send java class instance from javascript (via ajax) to jsp or servlet

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

I am trying to send the JAVA CLASS INSTANCE from my javascript code to the JSP file via ajax .   How can i send ? I tried sending the instance like this :

```
   data = {}
   data['my_instance'] = JAVA_CLASS_INSTANCE
```

and sending this data via ajax , problem is , in JSP, it is receiving it as a string rather than a class

By the way, I am getting the java class instance like this :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
     var class_instance = "<%= my_class_instance %>"; //if this method is wrong, plz tell me correct method to get instance and send via ajax. Already I have a form, along with the form data, i am trying to send this class also. If there is anyother good way for this, just tell me. 
</script>
```

Comment: Where are you getting this Java class instance in your JavaScript code? From an applet? Because without an applet, there's no Java class instance on the browser to send.

Comment: how could you send a java instance to client browser before you trying to send it back?

Comment: Re your edit: You don't have a Java class instance in your `class_instance` variable. At best you have a string; more likely you have a syntax error (it depends on what's in `my_class_instance`). If you think that's a Java class instance, you need to step back and study the fundamentals here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Updated below)*

Fundamentally, what you send from the client to the server via ajax is *always* a string. It can only be turned into something else by a server-side process interpreting it.

The question doesn't seem to make any sense. Unless you're using a Java applet on the client and [LiveConnect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LiveConnect), you don't have a Java class instance on the client at all.

If you **did** have a Java class instance on the client (e.g., from the applet), the only way to send it to the server would be:

1. [Serialize](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) it to a byte stream.
2. Encode that byte stream into a string (Base64 or similar).
3. Send that encoded string to the server via ajax.
4. Decode the string back into a byte stream on the server.
5. Deserialize it on the server.

...and there would almost certainly be a much better way of getting that information from the client to the server.

---

You've edited your question to say:

> By the way, I am getting the java class instance like this :
>
> ```
> <script type='text/javascript'>
>      var class_instance = "<%= my_class_instance %>";
> </script>
> ```

That won't give you a "Java class instance" on the browser. At best, you'll have a string with some information in it. More likely, depending on what's inside your `my_class_instance` server-side variable, you'll have a JavaScript syntax error. (E.g., if you have a `'` or a line break or an invalid JavaScript escape sequence, etc., inside it.)

If you believe that's a Java class instance, you need to step back and study the fundamentals of web applications before trying to write this code.

Comment: Please see updated question and tell me if i need to modify anything.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing `scriptlet` to your jsp. This is a bad thing 99.9% of times. You should avoid it  all the times. Most of the case, you can write it better with the `jstl`.

And more importantly, your code is not going to put the java object instance to client browser. It's totally wrong.

Please take a look.
[How to avoid using scriptlets in my JSP page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188706/how-to-avoid-using-scriptlets-in-my-jsp-page)