# How to URL encode a URL in JSP / JSTL?

Tags: java, html, jsp

I want to create an encoded [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator) for my site. Say for example, for this URL: "http://google.com/index.html"

I want to give this URL to the client by URL encoding it.

Comment: Why would you want to do this on a JSP ? Can't you just use [UrlEncoder.encode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) on the servlet and pass the data to the JSP ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Since you are using JSP, I would stick to [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) and [not use scriptlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188706/how-to-avoid-using-scriptlets-in-my-jsp-page). You could use the JSTL tag [`<c:url />` in combination with `<c:param />`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL4.html):

```
<c:url value="/yourClient" var="url">
  <c:param name="yourParamName" value="http://google.com/index.html" />
</c:url>

<a href="${url}">Link to your client</a>
```

This will result in:

```
<a href="/yourClient?yourParamName=http%3a%2f%2fgoogle.com%2findex.html">Link to your client</a>
```

Comment: How can I pass an empty param value? I've tried `<c:param name="DocType" value=""/>` but it results in `DocType%3d=`. I need only `DocType=`.

Comment: My expression fails since it includes a single quote there. (Poppo's Taqueria - Outpost). How can I solve by escaping, not replacing?

Comment: Single quotes don't need URL encoding.

Answer (score 5):

Using UrlEncoder.encode() is the answer. But the point is that this method doesn't percentage encode. Use:

```
java.net.UrlEncoder.encode(stringOfURL,"UTF-8").replace("+","%20")
```

Comment: should be java.net.URLEncoder not java.net.UrlEncoder

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is missing some JSP code to be valid, it should be:

```
<c:url value="/yourClient" var="url">
  <c:param name="yourParamName" value="http://google.com/index.html" />
</c:url>

<a href="<c:out value='${url}'/>">Link to your client</a>
```

As a comment pointed out, another option is to use JavaScripts [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) method.

Comment: ${url} and <c:out value="${url}"> work the same in this case