# Text box not accepting + sign

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

```
<input type="text" name="item" size=30 onKeyUp="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase()" value="<%=item%>">
```

on keying in **item value : 1016M012G+10/1K16:1-C**  but it displays me only 1016M012G 10/1K16:1-C without a plus sign after G

1016M012G/10/1K16:1-C works fine
1016M012G-10/1K16:1-C works fine

what is the problem??

Comment: works fine as far as I can tell: http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

When submitting the value of the input field, you have to encode the string to keep the "+" in there, beacause when submitting inside a URL the plus ("+") will be treated as a space, which is exactly what you end up with.

The solution to your problem should be found here: [How to URL encode a URL in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15923062/how-to-url-encode-a-url-in-jsp)