# Single quote in the URL parameter doesnt get replaced and encoded

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl, el, urlencode

In my code i'm trying to get a value that is set using a modelAttribute in a Spring controller and then pass it to Javascript function and set the value as a parameter in URL.

modelAttribute from the controller :

model.addAttribute("appName",appName);
model.addAttribute("cloverAppType", cloverAppType);

the javascript in the view :

```
 <a data-toggle="tab" onclick="loadOrders()">Orders</a>

  function loadOrders() {
    var message = "${appName}".replace(/'/g, "%27");
    var x = encodeURIComponent(message);
    window.location = '/admin/business/${businessId}/order?cloverAppType=${cloverAppType}&appName='+x;
   }
```

The issue is when a `'` is included in the appName it breaks the javascript and give the `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`
and `Uncaught ReferenceError: loadOrders is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick` errors on the browser console.

But if I hardcode the value `Poppo's Taqueria - Outpost` its being replaced and encoded.

How can I avoid this and pass the appName value with the `'` character as a aparameter of the URL?

Comment: try to `encode` first and then `replace`. Because if you replace before encode it also encode your `%` add in replace

Comment: I would take care of escaping in the EL expressions. For URL encoding use `c:url`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15923062/how-to-url-encode-a-url-in-jsp

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708242/how-to-escape-javascript-in-jsp

Comment: @JasperdeVries I cant find the escapeJS function in the tag library

Comment: You need to escape the single quotes in the URL to use it in a JavaScript string. There is no tag library. Please read the answer to that question carefully. You need to create a custom EL function as explained if you would like to take that route.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
var message = "${appName}".replace(/'/g, "%27");
```

to

```
var message = `${appName}`.replace(/'/g, "%27");
```

Comment: sorry it doesn't fix.

Comment: Can you share the entire script?

Comment: Where this "appName" comes from?
Can you give one example value?

Comment: 'Poppo's Taqueria - Outpost '
is  an example value. Its just a String value with single quote