# How to encode/decode query string from inside an html object tag?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, jstl

I have an object tag that I'm using its data attribute to call a servlet like the code bellow.
I'm passing a parameter to this url . 
in case the value of this parameter is not english > arabic for example.
then when I get this parameter value in the specified servlet > its value looks something like this "ÙŠØ¬Ø¨ Ø§Ù„ØªØÙ‚Ù‚ Ù…Ù†.pdf"

I tried to add some other query string parameter like 
    &&useUnicode=yes&&characterEncoding=UTF-8 
to the url but with no luck.
I also tried to use some code like 
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
to the servlet but with no luck too.

this is how my code look like :

```
<object data="servletName.ex?fileName=${fileNameValue}">click</object>
```

I want to get the arabic value as it is when i get the value of the file name parameter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to URL encode a URL in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15923062/how-to-url-encode-a-url-in-jsp)

Answer (score 0):

You need to URL-encode *fileNameValue*. You cannot tell the server which encoding to use for the URL by adding this info to the URL. The server needs to know BEFORE it reads the query - which is not possible. ;) Nowadays, you can safely assume that the server expects UTF-8. Makes sense - it should be prepared to understand those 2-byte Unicode Sequences. The only catch: URLs are not allowed to contain those characters. This is the reason for URL-Encoding / percent escaping.

If your filename would be "Über" - your request would be: "%C3%9Cber". This is a 2-byte url-encoded utf-8 encoded value of that first special character.