# Is there any difference between <jsp:scriptlet> and <% %>

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

Case 1

```
    <% 
    request.getParameter("");
    %>
   Enter code here
```

Case 2 jsp

```
  Scriptlet tag begin
     <jsp:scriptlet>
        request.getParameter("");
     </jsp:scriptlet>
   Scriplet tag close
```

Is there any difference between the two? Are the two, the same thing. Is anyone preferred over the other? According to `jsp2.0` scriptlets should be avoided. Do they talk about both these two?

Comment: Take a look at this one, might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files?rq=1

Comment: This one may also help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188706/how-to-avoid-using-scriptlets-in-my-jsp-page

Comment: no, it didnot help at all, before posting I went through both of these. They advocate the use of el and jstl tags which I already have started as a learning. My confusion is about jsp tags specifically scriptlet declaration and expression tag. like <jsp:scriptlet> <jsp:declaration> <jsp:expression> vs <% %> <%! %> <%= %>

Answer (score 0):

No difference between them except the syntax.Avoiding scriptlet means you need to avoid both of them

Comment: then why are there two different syntax for the same thing is what confused me.

Comment: @GauravArya sorry i dont know exactly