# display processes in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I have a problem when I desplay the process in jsp
I use the following code:

```
public ArrayList<String> getProcessusList(){

     ArrayList<String> ss=new ArrayList<String>();
     String st="";
 try {
        String line;
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec
                (System.getenv("windir") +"\\system32\\"+"tasklist.exe");
        BufferedReader input =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] se=line.split(" =\n");
            for(String sd:se){ss.add(sd);}
        }


        input.close();
    } catch (Exception err) {
        err.printStackTrace();
    }
 return ss;
}
```

and in jsp file the code is:

```
<body>
  ArrayList <String>processArray=p.getProcessusList();
  <%for(String se:processArray){
  String []s=se.split(" ");
  for(String sd:s){%><%=sd %>&nbsp;<% }%> <br><% } %>


  </body>
```

Output:

[image]

but I want to a format more user friendly,can you help me?

Comment: Use a monospaced font

Comment: @ofloflofl Henery's suggestion is much better than it seems.  But really, you have a lot of issues.  It is kind to stop the criticism at "this code is horribly non-portable".

Comment: i want to get the same format that displayed when i execute this code in java class (console)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution, some hard code:

```
public ArrayList<String> getProcessusList(){

        ArrayList<String> ss=new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            String line;
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec
                    (System.getenv("windir") +"\\system32\\"+"tasklist.exe");
            BufferedReader input =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] se=line.split(" =\n");
                for(String sd:se){
                    String[] sa = sd.split("\\s\\s+");
                    if (sa.length>1)
                        ss.add(sd);
                }
            }
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ss;
    }
```

JSP file:

```
<%
ArrayList<String> processArray=p.getProcessusList();
%>
<table border="1" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <%
            String se = processArray.get(0);
            String[] sa = se.split("\\s\\s+");%>
            <%for (int j=0;j<sa.length;j++){ 
            if(j==1){%>
            <th>PID</th>
            <th>Session Name</th>
            <%} else {%>
            <th><%=sa[j] %></th>
            <%}} %>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <%for (int i=1;i<processArray.size();i++){ 
        se = processArray.get(i);
        sa = se.split("\\s\\s+");%>
        <tr>
            <%for (int j=0;j<sa.length;j++){
            if(j==1){
                String ssa[] = sa[j].split(" ");%>
            <td><%=ssa[0] %></td>
            <td><%=ssa[1] %></td>
            <%}else{ %>
            <td><%=sa[j] %></td>
            <%}} %>
        </tr>
        <%} %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a `HTML table` and add rows(`tr`) and  `td's` to get proper structure.

Further you can do some `styling` to that with [CSS](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Overview.en.html).

Using scriplets in jsp is outdated and highly discouraged .Use JSTL instead of Scriplets

Mock Code

```
   <c:forEach items="${element}" var="myCollection">

    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${element.field}"/></td>

    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Prefer to read : [How to avoid using scriptlets in my JSP page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188706/how-to-avoid-using-scriptlets-in-my-jsp-page)

Answer (score 0):

Add html table (or div) and use JSTL to generate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#rightPad%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

```
StringUtils.rightPad(sd,30);
```