# My jsp printing 'null' instead of null

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, oracle11g

I am reading a String value from database and printing it onto a jsp page through a servlet. The Problem is that on the Jsp the String 'null' is getting printed in case the field in the database is null. I need to have a blank editbox instead if the value in the database is null.

My database Access Object:

```
 public String getVerEmpId(retailcustomervergobean rcvb) {
        String var = "";
        custid = rcvb.getCustid();
        Connection conn;
        try {
            conn = db.getDbConnection();
            String sql = "select CUST_EMP_ID from retail_cif_master where cust_id = ?";
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, custid.toUpperCase());
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                var = rs.getString("CUST_EMP_ID");
            }
        } catch (Exception asd) {
            System.out.println(asd.getMessage());
        }
        return var;
    }
```

My Servlet:

```
String custempid = rcvd.getVerEmpId(rcvb);
request.setAttribute("custempid", custempid);
```

My Jsp:

```
name="custEmpId" readonly="true" value="<%=request.getAttribute("custempid")%>"
```

My Display if the field is null:
[image: My Display]

My database is Oracle 11g and Browser is FireFox.

Comment: Why don't you check the String for null-value in the Servlet Code? Or you could use Expression Language in the JSP

Comment: Can you check that your value is not "null" in the database (string "null" instead of null value).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should avoid using scriplets in JSP. Use JSTL and EL instead.

You need to test for `null` string before printing your value. When you try to print an object reference which is `null`, the `null` reference is converted to `"null"` string.

This is how you pre-test for `null` using EL:

```html
<c:out value="${not empty custempid ? custempid: ''}" />
```

Note that `not empty` will check for both `null` and empty string.

**See also:**

- [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1679863)
- [How to avoid using scriptlets in my JSP page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2188706/1679863)

Comment: As simple as you can.That's it. :)

Answer (score 2):

You would try something like:

```
<%=request.getAttribute("custempid") == null ? "" : request.getAttribute("custempid") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this way

```
String x=request.getAttribute("custempid");
if(x.equals("null"))
x=""

name="custEmpId" readonly="true" value="<%=x%>"
```

**note**
use jstl/el instead of using scriplets

Answer (score 0):

The [getAttribute()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.servlet/servlet-api/2.4/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.java#ServletRequest.getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) method returns Object

> an Object containing the value of the attribute, or null if the attribute does not exist.

And when you try to convert it to String directly it invokes

[String.valueOf(Object obj)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Object%29)

> if the argument is null, then a string equal to "null"; otherwise, the value of obj.toString() is returned.

So add a null check/empty string check. or now a days no one using scriplets and as Rohit suggested movie to Expression language,which makes life easy

Answer (score 0):

It is printing null because the field value itself is NULL. If the query were returning an empty resultset then it would've printed a blank.If you want to enforce a different behaviour, add a custom condition like

```
if(custempid==null)
 custempid="";
```