# multiple checkboxes to HttpServletRequest JSP

Tags: html, jsp, servlets, request

I am new to JSP, and i want to make a simple crud application. I want to save a Meal, wich consists of a number of ingredients, the problem is that you don't know how many.

I have this code within a `<form action="Controller" method=POST">`.

The fault in the current code is that that HTTPServletRequest will only know that last checkbox, since all the checkboxes have the same 'name'. But as I don't know the number of ingredients the user will add i cannot number them accordingly. Is there a way to send a List to my controller ?

```
                                <%
                                    List<Ingredient> ingredients = (List) request.getAttribute("ingredients");
                                %>
                                <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                                    <% for (Ingredient ingredient : ingredients) {%>
                                    <label class="btn btn-primary">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedIngredients" value="<%=ingredient.getName()%>"><%=ingredient.getName()%>
                                    </label>                                      
                                    <% }%>
                                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must simply use `request.getParameterValues("SelectedIngredients")` to get all the checked ingredients, as a `String[]`.

Please read [How to avoid using scriptlets in my JSP page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188706/how-to-avoid-using-scriptlets-in-my-jsp-page).

Answer (score 1):

You should use getParameterValues().

See: http://www.coderanch.com/t/603190/Servlets/java/Retrieve-array-parameters-request