# How to iterate list in JSTL?

Tags: jsp, jstl

```
<c:forEach items="<% EasyLookUp.lookUpList(EasyLookUp.PriceSources); %>" var="priceSourceItem">
                                    ${priceSourceItem }
                                </c:forEach>
```

this is my code, but the page display

[image]

there is just one record, and the java code did not work. can anybody tell me how to handle it?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use scriptlets:

- [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)
- [How to avoid using scriptlets in my JSP page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188706/how-to-avoid-using-scriptlets-in-my-jsp-page)

Write a `Servlet` that forwards to your JSP resource. In that `Servlet`'s `service(..)` method (or the `HttpServlet`'s `doXXX(..)` method), add a request attribute with the return value of your `EasyLookup` method.

```
request.setAttribute("lookupResult", EasyLookUp.lookUpList(EasyLookUp.PriceSources));
// forward to JSP
```

Then use EL to resolve the attribute in your JSP

```
<c:forEach items="${lookupResult}" var="priceSourceItem">
     ${priceSourceItem }
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: I got my solution:`<%
          pageContext.setAttribute("PriceSources", EasyLookUp.lookUpList(EasyLookUp.PriceSources));
        %>
         <c:forEach items="${PriceSources }" var="priceSourceItem">
          ${priceSourceItem }
         </c:forEach>`
but I think your solution is better, but not fit for me.

Comment: @jesse Yes, you are using page attributes, which are a scope more restrictive than request attributes. If you take anything away from my answer, it should be this: **don't use scriptlets**.

Comment: your anwser is excellent, we should avoid scriptlets, but the attributes in my bean is all original， it can not display on page.

Comment: @jesse Sorry, I did not understand. What did you mean by _bean_ and _original_? You mean you don't know what type  `lookUpList` will return?

Comment: for example country, the column in bean is countryId, just like 1, 2... but on page, it should show as "US", "UK". My English is not good~ I don't know how to express it accurately

Answer (score 1):

In **foreach** loop of **jstl** there is no need to pass the list with jstl tag

```
<c:forEach items="${EasyLookUp.PriceSources}" var="priceSourceItem">
       ${priceSourceItem }
</c:forEach>
```