# retrieve data from database table and display it in atable with html

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jdbc, scriptlet

i am a beginer and am currently working on my final school project which require retrieving data from a database table and displaying the datas in an html page. i have searched alot but still no progress. i was linked to this site through google, i saw a format and i try to do the same thing but after running the code i get this error

**Exception report**

```
message An exception occurred processing JSP page /crimeinfo.jsp at line 32 description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
```

**exception**

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /crimeinfo.jsp at line 32
29:     
30:     
31:     <%List <String> data =(List)request.getAttribute("data");
32:     Iterator <String> itr = data.iterator() ;
33:     for (itr = data.iterator();
34:     itr.hasNext();)
35:     {%>
```

please i need help. i dont known what else to do. thnks...

**viewcrime.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--web.xml code-->
<servlet>
<servlet-name>viewcrimereport</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>viewcrimereport</servlet-class>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>viewcrimereport</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>viewcrimereport</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping></servlet>
```

**viewcrimereport.java**

```
public class viewcrimereport extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet implements javax.servlet.Servlet {
     private ServletConfig config;
     String page = "crimeinfo.jsp";
     public void init(ServletConfig config)
         throws ServletException{
         this.config = config; }
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    Connection conn = null;
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/citycrime";
    String userName = "root";
    String passw = "jids";
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet rs;
    ArrayList<String> datalist = new ArrayList<String>();
    try{    
            int i=0;
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, passw);
        pst = conn.prepareStatement("");
    String sql ="select suspectname,suspectaliases,suspectht,suspectgender,features,crimeaddress,crimetype,caseno,casestatus from crimereport";
        pst.executeQuery(sql);
        rs = pst.getResultSet();
        while(rs.next()){
            datalist.add(rs.getString("suspectname"));
            datalist.add(rs.getString("suspectaliases"));
            datalist.add(rs.getString("suspectht"));
            datalist.add(rs.getString("suspectgender"));
            datalist.add(rs.getString("features"));
            datalist.add(rs.getString("crimeaddress"));
            datalist.add(rs.getString("crimetype"));
            datalist.add(rs.getString("caseno"));
            datalist.add(rs.getString("casestatus"));}
        rs.close();pst.close(); }
    catch(Exception e){System.out.println("Exception is;"+e);}
    request.setAttribute("data",datalist);
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(page);
    if (dispatcher != null){
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
        }
}
```

**crimeinfo.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.sql.*" import="java.util.*" 
contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4
/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Crime Report</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1" with="600">
    <tr><td><tb><td>SuspectName</td></b>
    <td><tb>SuspectAlias</b></td>
    <td><tb>suspectaliases</tb></td>
    <td><tb>Height</tb></td>
    <td><tb>suspectht</tb></td>
    <td><tb>Gender</tb></td>
    <td><tb>suspectgender</tb></td>
    <td><tb>Features</tb></td>
    <td><tb>features</tb></td>
    <td><tb>Address</tb></td>
    <td><tb>crimeaddress</tb></td>
    <td><tb>CrimeType</tb></td>
    <td><tb>crimetype</tb></td>
    <td><tb>CaseNumber</tb></td>
    <td><tb>caseno</tb></td>
    <td><tb>Status</tb></td>
    <td><tb>casestatus</tb></td></tr>
    <% Iterator <String> itr;%>
    <%List data =(List)request.getAttribute("datalist");
    for (itr = data.iterator();
    itr.hasNext();){%><tr>
    <%String s =(String)itr.next(); %>
    <td><%=itr.next()%>></td>
    <tr><td><%=itr.next()%>></td>
    <tr><td><%=itr.next()%>></td>
    <tr><td><%=itr.next()%>></td>
    <tr><td><%=itr.next()%>></td>
    <tr><td><%=itr.next()%>></td>
    <tr><td><%=itr.next()%>></td>
        <tr><td><%=itr.next()%>></td>
        <tr><td><%=itr.next()%>></td>
<tr><td><%=itr.next()%>></td>
    <tr><td><%=itr.next()%>></td>
    <tr><td><%=itr.next()%>></td>
    <tr><td><%=itr.next()%>></td>
    <tr><td><%=itr.next()%>></td>
    <tr><td><%=itr.next()%>></td>
    <tr><td><%=itr.next()%>></td>
    <tr><td><%=itr.next()%>></td></tr><%} %>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please for better understanding of this the firts code is the xml code viewcrimereport.xml

Comment: seriously poor formatting. and "data" is itself plural of "datum". there is nothing called "datas"

Comment: @user354361 i have answered your question, comment if you face further problem

Answer (score 2):

1. At line 32, make it `Iterator itr = data.iterator() ;` I advise you to use `while(itr.hasNext()` instaed of for loop for more clarity of the code. Also, the initialization part in the for loop is retundant.
2. rename your xml file to `web.xml` and put it as `\WEB-INF\web.xml`
3. in web.xml, url-pattern should be `<url-pattern>/viewcrimereport</url-pattern>`
4. for your servlet, since you have already extended `HttpServlet` class, there is no need to implement `Servlet` interface. HttpServlet class already implements that interface
5. you have not closed your connection. use `conn.close()`.
6. in your jsp, it should be `<%List data =(List)request.getAttribute("data");` because you have set request attribute with name `data` and not "datalist"
7. use of scriptlets (those `<%   %>` things) are discouraged. [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188706/how-to-avoid-using-scriptlets-in-my-jsp-page)
8. since you are not outputting anything from your servlet to your browser, you can omit the following code `PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
   response.setContentType("text/html");`
9. in my personal opinion, i would suggest to use `service` instead of `doGet()`. Service method will itself call the doGet method. Plus it can also invoke other meyhods like doPost, doHead etc if it requires.

Comment: thanks for your help. i have made all the correction you advised and got this error message.                                              org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /crimeinfo.jsp at line 32

29:  
30:  
31:  <%List data =(List)request.getAttribute("data");
32:  Iterator <String> itr = data.iterator() ;
33:  for (itr = data.iterator();
34:   itr.hasNext();)
35:   {%>

Comment: same eexception that you got earlier? i think you missed my first point.

Comment: i did exactly what you advised.... this is the code
 <%List data =(List)request.getAttribute("data");
 Iterator <String> itr = data.iterator() ;
 for (itr = data.iterator();
  itr.hasNext();)
  {%>

Comment: sorry, my mistake. I forgot to edit that one. Now i have updated my fiest point.

Comment: I suggest you to use jstl tags for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `datalist.get(column index)` method of `ArrayList`. For more details refer to:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arraylist_class.htm

Comment: @hutchonoid This isn't a link only answer. It is messy and should be reformatted/cleaned up. See Your Answer is in Another Castle, When an Answer is not an Answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer