# how to use condition statements in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a servlet class for login process, if the username or password is incorrect I want to set two attributes to the request, one attribute is boolean `authentication_error`, the second is string `authentication_error_message`.

I want to make a condition statement to print the `authentication_error_message` if the `authentication_error` is true.

```
req.setAttribute("authentication_error", false);

if(!query.list().isEmpty()){
    List<?> list = query.list();
    Admin student = (Admin)list.get(0);
    req.setAttribute("username", student.getUsername());
}
else{

    req.setAttribute("authentication_error_message", "username or password is incorrect!");
    req.setAttribute("authentication_error", true);
}

req.getRequestDispatcher("/views/login.jsp").forward(req, res);
```

How I can write this statement in jsp?

**N.B: preferr to not use jstl.**

Comment: Why not using JSTL ? It's much nicer than mixed Java, HTML and JS

Comment: You could forward to two different jsps, as there are different attributes, Otherwise jstl `<c:if test="...">` is still the most compact way.

Comment: @Dici because I already know how to do it with jstl, I just asked for an alternative, thanks!

Comment: @Mohammad but there is no *better* alternative, just fo you to know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scriptlets are not recommended, JSTL is the way to go for these scenarios.
That being said, a different way could be scriptlets.

Scriptlet syntax example:

```
<%
 String userName="";

if(statement){
 userName=request.getParameter("userName");
  }
%>
```

See source here [Java code inside JSP page](http://five.agency/java-code-inside-jsp-page/).

How to avoid using scriptlets [How to avoid using scriptlets in my JSP page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188706/how-to-avoid-using-scriptlets-in-my-jsp-page)

Answer (score 0):

You can use scriplet if you don't prefer to use JSTL.

Below code snippet is demonstration on how we can use condition statements in JSP.

```
<% if("true".equals      (request.getParameter ("authentication_error"))) {
%>
  authentication_error_message
<% }
else {
%>      
   Other Message
<%  } %>
```