# assigning unique ID to HTML tag in JSP by java code

Tags: java, html, jsp

I'm creating an HTML table dynamically in a JSP using Java for loop.
But when I'm trying to assign a unique id to each TD by its position in table,
I get a compilation error.

what I would like to do is some sort of:

```
<TD id="<% new String(row*ROWS+col) %>>
```

this is the code of the jsp:

```
        <TABLE border="1">
        <% for (int row = 1; row <= ROWS; row++) { %>
        <TR>
            <%      for (int col = 1; col <= COLS; col++) {%>
            <TD id="????"> (<%=col%>, <%=row%>)
            </TD>
            <% } %>
        </TR>
        <% } %>
    </TABLE>
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `=`. Also, the String class doesn't have a constructor with a int parameter.

```
<TD id="<%= row * ROWS + col %>> ">
```

By the way, the use of scriptlets are not recommended in JSP pages, you could get some info in these questions:

[How to avoid using scriptlets in my JSP page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188706/how-to-avoid-using-scriptlets-in-my-jsp-page)

[How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files?lq=1)

Comment: tried it, but it doesnt work. I also tried with " in the end of the expression, or ; after the new command. actually what I get as an error is:  "Bad value "   " for attribute "id" on element "td": An ID must not contain whitespace.
Syntax of id:
An ID consists of at least one character but must not contain any whitespace."