# Writing java codes in jsp(Spring Mvc)

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I am new to spring MVC. I need to write java codes in a jsp(though its not a good practice, but i don't have other option). 
My Jsp is now like

```
          <c:forEach items="${dbEntries}" var="c" varStatus="loop">
                        <tr> 
                              <% 
                                  int i = 0;
                                  system.out.println(i);
                              %>
                              <td rowspan="1">${c.getRh_name()}</td>                                 
                              <td rowspan="1">${c.getIpm_name()}</td>` 
                        </tr>
          </c:forEach>
```

but its giving an error "org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:". Can anyone help??

included headers are

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"  prefix="spring"%>
<core:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>
<%@taglib  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

full exception stacktrace
Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:490)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:379)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:341)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:662)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:364)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Comment: post your full exception stacktrace. Also post what header you have included in your jsp

Comment: @ArpanDas I have edited the post now.

Comment: system must be capitalized `System.out.println(i)`

Comment: thanks @GurkanYesilyurt. but it is not displaying the variable i. can you help me with that ??

Comment: system.out.println(i) for debugging on console, use `out.println(i)` for jsp page.

Comment: @GurkanYesilyurt thanks again. Now if i want to print the variable i in a header or paragraph tag what should i do??

Comment: you need continuously close and open `<% %>` tags if you want to use scriptlets. But you had better use only JSTL/ EL /Spring Tags expressions to avoid such a mixing. [How to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188706/how-to-avoid-using-scriptlets-in-my-jsp-page)

Comment: @GurkanYesilyurt please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49423872/accessing-a-variable-outside-java-code-fragment-in-a-jspspring-mvc

Answer (score 0):

Use jstl instead of java code inside jsp like this.

```
<c:set var="salary" scope="session" value="${2000*2}" /> 
 <c:out value="${salary}" /> 
<c:forEach begin="1" end="5" step="1">
     <c:set var="salary" value="${2000*2}" /> 
</c:forEach> <c:out value="${salary}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`<td>${loop.count}</td>` will return you the count of iteration going on. Its like `i+1` in for loop `for(int i=0;i<10;i++);`