# Accessing a variable outside java code fragment in a jsp(Spring MVC)

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

in my scenario i have a code like below:

```
     <c:forEach items="${dbEntries}" var="c" varStatus="loop">
                    <tr> 
                          <% 
                              int i = 0;
                              System.out.println(i);
                          %>
                          <td rowspan="1">${c.getRh_name()}</td>                                 
                          <td rowspan="1">${c.getIpm_name()}</td>` 
                    </tr>
      </c:forEach>
```

now i want to access the variable from html. like below

```
<h1>${i}</h1>
```

but its not displaying.can anyone help??

Comment: you can set i varilbe in request scope `request.setAttribute("variableName",i)` and access `<h1>${variableName}</h1>`. <h1> tag is out of the foreach or?

Comment: @GurkanYesilyurt where will i declare this request.setAttribute("variableName",i) . I mean in <% %> ??

Comment: yes, expressions (EL) like ${anything} works with scopes (request, session etc.). If you access any variable you can set it in any scope before.

Comment: for this you can use jstl also.

Comment: @SanjayPatel can you write the code using jstl??

Comment: <c:set var="salary" scope="session" value="${2000*2}" />

 <c:out value="${salary}" />

 <c:forEach begin="1" end="5" step="1">
  <c:set var="salary" value="${2000*2}" />
 </c:forEach>

 <c:out value="${salary}" />

Comment: @SanjayPatel thanks a ton .:)

Comment: Pl upvote if this answer is useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing java codes in jsp(Spring Mvc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49422287/writing-java-codes-in-jspspring-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

Use jstl instead of java code inside jsp like this.

```
    <c:set var="salary" scope="session" value="${2000*2}" /> 
     <c:out value="${salary}" /> 
    <c:forEach begin="1" end="5" step="1">
         <c:set var="salary" value="${2000*2}" /> 
    </c:forEach> <c:out value="${salary}" />
```