# EL expressions are not evaluated in JBoss AS 4.2.2

Tags: java, jsp, el

EL expressions are not evaluated in JBoss AS 4.2.2. I have `web.xml` declared conform the Servlet 2.4 spec.

```xml
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
```

What needs to be done more in order to get EL to work in JBoss AS 4.2.2?

Answer (score 2):

Your `web.xml` root declaration looks fine.

Other causes to exclude:

- Ensure that you don't have Servlet/JSP/EL libraries of a different servletcontainer make/version in your webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` like `servlet-api.jar`, `jsp-api.jar`, `el-api.jar`, etc. More than often starters drop a copy of those files from unknown resource in there to overcome compilation problems, [but that's the wrong approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project)!
- Ensure that you don't have `<%@page isELIgnored="true" %>` in your JSPs.
- Ensure that you don't have the following in your `web.xml`:

  ```xml
  <jsp-config>
      <el-ignored>true</el-ignored>
  <jsp-config>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<%@page isELIgnored="false" %>
```

in your JSP.

I had a similar issue with Tomcat 6. Even though EL was not disabled globally (thru web.xml). I had to individually enable EL in my JSPs thru the above statement.

Comment: This by the way implies that the Tomcat of the host where you deployed the webapp to has a `<el-ignored>true</el-ignored>` in its `/conf/web.xml`.