# Expression language, don't show variable value

Tags: java, jsp, el

I am pretty new in Java EE, i am trying use that `.war` file http://community.jboss.org/wiki/ThreadDumpJSP , but it seems `index.jsp` file doesn't show variable, I see only `${thr.name}   ${thr.state}    ${thr.priority} ${thr.daemon}` I am tested it on `jboss` and `tomcat 6`

edit:

here is code:

```
package org.jboss.varia.threaddump.ThreadDumpBean;

import java.io.Serializable;import java.util.*;

public class ThreadDumpBean implements Serializable {

    private final Map traces;

    public ThreadDumpBean() {traces = new TreeMap(THREAD_COMP);traces.putAll(Thread.getAllStackTraces());}

    public Collection getThreads() {return traces.keySet();}

    public Map getTraces() {return traces;}

    /*** Compare the threads by name and id.*/
    private static final Comparator THREAD_COMP = new Comparator() {  
        public int compare(Thread o1, Thread o2) {    
            int result = o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());    
            if (result == 0) {      
                Long id1 = o1.getId();      
                Long id2 = o2.getId();      
                return id1.compareTo(id2);    
            }    
            return result;  
        }};
}
```

and `.jsp`:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>

<jsp:useBean id="threadDump"
             class="org.jboss.varia.threaddump.ThreadDumpBean"
             scope="request"/>

<html>
<body>
<h2>Thread Summary</h2>
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
  <tr>
    <th>Thread</th>
    <th>State</th>
    <th>Priority</th>
    <th>Daemon</th>
  </tr>
  <c:forEach items="${threadDump.threads}" var="thr">
    <tr>
      <td><c:out value='<a href="#${thr.id}">${thr.name}</a>' escapeXml="false"/></td>
      <td><c:out value="${thr.state}"/></td>
      <td><c:out value="${thr.priority}"/></td>
      <td><c:out value="${thr.daemon}"/></td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</table>

<h2>Thread Stack Traces</h2>
<c:forEach items="${threadDump.stackTraces}" var="trace">
  <h4><c:out value='<a name="${trace.key.id}">${trace.key}</a>' escapeXml="false"/></h4>
  <pre>
  <c:forEach items="${trace.value}" var="traceline">
      at <c:out value="${traceline}"/></c:forEach>
  </pre>
</c:forEach>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I found code here: http://itblackbelt.wordpress.com/2006/09/12/thread-dump-jsp-in-java-5-by-dr-heinz-m-kabutz-jdk-version-jdk-15/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you deploy the JSP page on Tomcat 6 you need to enable the expression language to use it (for reasons of backwards compatibility this is disabled by default). That can either be done by creating a web.xml file where the version of the Servlet spec is set to at least 2.4. Your web.xml file should look something like this:

```
<web-app id="TreadDumpApp" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee";
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd";>

</web-app>
```

To use EL outside JSP tag attributes, you need to add event more magic to the web.xml

```
<web-app {...magic from above...}>    
<jsp-property-group>  
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
<el-ignore>false</el-ignore>
</jsp-property-group>
</web-app>
```

You should also be able to force this single page to allow EL, but adding this declaration in the top of the page:

```
<%@ page isELIgnored ="false" %>
```

Yeah, that double negation is quite elegant, eh? ;-)