# Get Parameter From URL in JSP

Tags: jsp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get parameters from the URL with JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890438/how-to-get-parameters-from-the-url-with-jsp)

Help please!
I want to extract sessid from "`http://111.0000.0000.0000/2-abc-xyz?sessid=32323232-232322323`" using JSP .

Answer (score 4):

Try

EL expression

```
${param.sessid}
```

Or  Java code.

```
String value=request.getParameter("sessid");
```

Or

Use java.net.URI,

```
URI uri=new URI("http://111.0000.0000.0000/2-abc-xyz?sessid=32323232-232322323");
System.out.println(uri.getQuery());
```