# How to get data from other jsp file?

Tags: mysql, string, jsp

I wanna execute this query:

```
String query = "select login,full_name from users where team_id='" + a + "'";
```

`a` is a variable, to which i save a column data in another file (not in this, where Im trying to execute query)

How can I use this variable `a`, if it is in another file?

Comment: The question is not clear. I am voting for close. Please Provide relevant details and your efforts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check here on how to get parameter value on url

[How to get parameters from the URL with JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890438/how-to-get-parameters-from-the-url-with-jsp)