# "GET" value in JSP with Spring MVC

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am trying to get the "registo" value from the folowing url:

> `http://localhost:83/spring/login?registo=sucesso`

in my jsp file.

What I have tried so far:

```xml
<c:if test="${not empty request.getAttribute('registo')}">
    ....
</c:if>

<c:if test="${not empty registo}">
    ...
</c:if>
```

and some more that I don't remember.

Any advice?

Comment: is `registo` a URL parameter?

Comment: Try the param map: `<c:if test="${empty param['registo']}>...</c:if>`

Comment: @VPK: yes, see the URL in his post

Comment: Thanks Alexander! That solved it. I can mark it as the answer if you post it :)

Comment: Duplicate of `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890438/how-to-get-parameters-from-the-url-with-jsp`