# Adding Parameters to Hello World JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans-8

I'm new to this so i'm sure there is a simple solution but the question I'm trying to answer is this "This page should display a simple hello world message. In addition, your JSP page should look for a parameter in the request (GET) named “user”. If the user parameter is present, it should read the name from the request and display a greeting to the user. If the parameter is not present, it should display a generic “Hello World” message"

So far what I have is this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Hello World - JSP tutorial</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%= "Hello World!" %>
</body>
</html>
```

How would I go about adding the parameters?

Comment: you can use `request.getParameter("parameterName")` to get the parameter  but first you need a good tutorial for jsp.

Comment: Please go though link .Have you search before asking?

[how-to-get-parameters-from-the-url-with-jsp-link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890438/how-to-get-parameters-from-the-url-with-jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it goes:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Hello World - JSP tutorial</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
   String user = request.getParameter("user");
   response.getWriter().println(user == null ? ("Hello World") : ("Hello World " + user)); 
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @JoeySchwind don't do it this way! Scriptlets in a JSP have long been highly not recommended. Use [JSTL](https://jstl.java.net/).

Comment: This is far from good practice. I wouldn't recommend this approach to anyone, let alone someone trying to learn to code.

Comment: @Boris Oops.. I touched JSP 3years ago. May be I'm so outdated. Can you put out a sample then?

Comment: Can't right now - but there are plenty of [examples on the internet)(http://exampledepot.8waytrips.com/egs/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core/getparam.html).