# Sending two attributes in Servlet RequestDispatcher

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am uploading an image through Servlet.

```
try{
    //Image Upload Code
} catch(Exception e){
    //Exception Handler
} finally {
    request.setAttribute("job-id", jobId);
    request.setAttribute("message", message);
    System.out.println("SJA : " + message);
    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("ReloadJob.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

Then, on ReloadJob.jsp, I am trying to use these attached attributes:

```
String jobId = request.getParameter("job-id");
String message = request.getParameter("message");
System.out.println("RJ : " + jobId);
System.out.println("RJ : " + message);
```

This whole process prints following output:

```
SJA : MESSAGE RECEIVED
RJ : BYWEGRI76T46U34T
RJ : null
```

Why is **message** variable null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String message=(String)request.getAttribute("message");`

`getParameter()` returns http request parameters. Those passed from the client to the server.

`getAttribute()` is for server-side usage only - you fill the request with attributes that you can use within the same request.

For example - you set an attribute in a servlet, and read it from a JSP. It can be used for any object, not just string.

Comment: Anptk  What u change??

Answer (score 1):

try to use

```
   String message=(String)request.getAttribute("message");
```

Comment: It worked. Can you tell me why `jobId` variable was working with `getParameter`? and `message` variable didn't?

Comment: Because it was sent as an URL parameter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890438/how-to-get-parameters-from-the-url-with-jsp

Comment: This is because same request reference is forwarded using RequestDispatcher in which jobId parameter was received.

Comment: mark this answer as correct if it's resolved your problem