# How to fetch images from previous page to next page in a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I am creating a webpage where I am displaying images and checkboxes for each image to be selected. What I want to do is when a user clicks on multiple checkboxes and moves to next page, the user should get the name as well as the image displayed on the next page, similar to that in e-commerce sites when a user selects multiple items and clicks on add to cart option and proceeds he/she gets the name of the item as well as the images displayed on the next page.

I found a similar question but the problem is I don't want to implement in php as I don't know it, is there any other way to proceed with servlets, jsp or javascript?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: use query string if you want to show name and image like `product.jsp?productid=12`

Comment: @NijrajGelani it should be jsp session

Comment: @FastSnail Sorry, didn't notice that tag there.

Comment: @FastSnail can you show me a sample code

Comment: @user5451270 example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890438/how-to-get-parameters-from-the-url-with-jsp