# Opening new window with parameter in javascript

Tags: javascript, jstl

I have below javascript function . I am trying to open a jsp in new window and pass some values from this function :

```
function editStudent(fname){
    alert("hi");
    var editWindow = window.open("studentEdit.jsp?fname="+fname, " ", "width=300,height=300");
    editWindow.focus();
}
```

Above javascript function will be called on button click. New window is opening but the parameter is returning 'null' in the studentEdit.jsp

Comment: How are you calling your `editStudent` function? Can you show

Comment: Does fname have a value? You can change alert("hi") to alert("fname="+fname).

Comment: fname is having value and alert("fname="+fname) is displaying value also but in the new window 'studentEdit.jsp' value of 'fname' is coming as null

Comment: Whats the code that picks the value from the URL in studentEdit.jsp?

Comment: @putvande its an input tag , I am using jstl <input type="text" name="fname" value="${fname}">

Comment: So maybe thats where the issues is as you say the alert gives you a value for `fname` and the rest of the JS looks all valid.

Comment: @putvande But I need to display the value of 'fname' in text box in studentEdit.jsp .How do I acheive this ?

Comment: I don't know anything about jstl to be honest, thats why I tagged your question with it so maybe someone else can help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need:

```
<input type="text" name="fname" value="${param.fname}">
```

This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1890462/989516