# What does "?" tag while calling jsp mean?

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

```
show-product.jsp?id=HC
```

what will show-product.jsp get? And how can I reach those values in jsp file? How to get parameters from the URL with JSP

Comment: And this one answers the second question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890438/how-to-get-parameters-from-the-url-with-jsp

Comment: Yes you are right! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is what is called a `query` string, and you can retrieve the value from the query string by calling the `getParameter` function.

```
<%= request.getParameter("id") %>
```

In the example you provided, it will return "HC".