# How to get URL parameter at JSP and put it to hidden input using Liferay 7

Tags: java, jsp, url, liferay-7

I want to get parameter from URL and set it as value to hidden input. I tried it like I did when I used Servlet API. It doesn't work. (value=0). Also I checked this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890438/how-to-get-parameters-from-the-url-with-jsp). And nothing helped. Also I tried to use scriptlets `<input type="hidden" name="views" value="<%PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(request).getParameter("views").toString();%>">`

But it doesn't work too. How to extract it in liferay7 portlet and set to input?

Comment: Can you print `String view = request.getParameter("views")`and check whether you are getting the value?

Comment: @soorapadman, I tried this way, but no results

Answer (score 1):

```
HttpServletRequest httpReq = PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(renderRequest));
String abc = httpReq.getParameter("abc");
```

As stated at https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/9784835

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use ParamUtil. Hope this will help.

```
String myUserName = ParamUtil.getString(request, "views");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create renderURL with your parameter, smth like that:

`<portlet:renderURL var="anyNameYouWantUrl" copyCurrentRenderParameters="true">
    <portlet:param name="anyName" value="anyValue"/>
</portlet:renderURL>`

--

`copyCurrentRenderParameters="true"` will save your render parameter and you can easily set it to hidden input using action method.