# passing data between two jsp pages using jquery

Tags: jquery, jsp

I know this question seems already asked.. But i surfed through the websites and i did not get any clarification. Here is my question.
 I have two web pages. Call them as page1.jsp and page2.jsp.
  I am having a table in my page1.jsp. Please refer the image [image: Please refer the image]

And in my page2.jsp i am having an input field like in the following image
[image]

Now I need to display the the respective docId in the textarea which i am clicking in the page1.jsp.

For example if i am clicking 00001 in page1.jsp i needs to redirect to page2.jsp and 00001 should be updated textarea of in page2.jsp

the script i used in page1.jsp is

```
$('.pending_list').click(function(){
            var row = $(this).closest("tr"); 
            var text = row.find(".pending_list").text(); 
            alert(text);
            var DocNo = text;
            $('.pending_list').attr({
                href:"${loginbean.contextPath}/effortloading/search"

            });         
        });
```

Here is my page2.jsp

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                            <div class="row padding6">
                                                <div
                                                    class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 margintop8  rq-field">
                                                    <!-- for field required notification-->
                                                    <spring:message text="Doc No" />
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                                    <form:input id="docID" path="DOC_ID" name="DOC_ID" type="text"
                                                        class="form-control" />
                                                    <form:errors path="userTitle" class="control-label" />
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/effortloading/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String effortloadingsearch(@Valid @ModelAttribute("loginbean") Loginbean loginbean,EffortLoadingBean effortBean, Model model,BindingResult result){
        model.addAttribute("effortloadingedit", effortBean);
        return "EffortLoadingSearch";
    }
```

I hope my question is understandable.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a bare minimum you can pass your `docId` in the url itself from *page1* and then later in *page2* you can get it from your url and put it in the search area.

A little code to understand

In *page1* :

```
    $('.pending_list').click(function(){
        var row = $(this).closest("tr"); 
        var text = row.find(".pending_list").text(); 
        alert(text);
        var DocNo = text;
        $('.pending_list').attr({
            //SEND YOUR DOCID IN THE URL
            href:"${loginbean.contextPath}/effortloading/search?docId=" + GET_ID_HERE
        });         
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer abdullah.. If i pass my DocId in this url how can i get that in my page2??

Comment: post some code where you are handling the displaying of page2.jsp

Comment: I taken the DocId in the URL. But i don't know how to pass that to the textarea in page2. Please help

Comment: You will have to get the `docId` from the url using `@RequestParam` in your controller method then pass that in the model and display in the jsp. Please post the controller method that opens the page2

Comment: I added the controller.. Now My DocId is coming in my URL of my page2. I don't have any issues in that.. But now the problem is how to pass the docId from the URL into textarea?

Comment: you can use `<%= request.getParameter("DocNo") %>` in your page2 now.

Comment: Sorry for asking more and more questions. I am new to Jquery.. Do i need to add the above code in my html or in script??

Comment: You have to use `<%= request.getParameter("DocNo") %>` in your page2.jsp file. `<%= %>` is a jsp tag which is used to execute java codes.

Comment: You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1890451/3094731) answer to get an idea on how to get data from the url in jsp.

Comment: I am getting the DocId in my page2. How to pass that to textarea?

Comment: Please take a look at [this](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-textbox-example/) blog.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr.Abdullah.. Thank u for ur time

Comment: Glad I could help brother.

Comment: Hey.. U helped to sister.. Not Brother :D

Comment: :D Shan is my brothers name. Anyway i am glad i could help you sister :)

Answer (score 0):

While forming the URL of [00001](/page2.jsp?passedValue=00001) in page1.jsp you can append query parameter and this query parameter can be used in second page to populate the text area.

Comment: I taken that DocNo in my URL.. How to populate that in my textarea??