# Cannot resolve method getParameter() in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea

I'm building a small project in JSP. I want to take data from a HTML sign up form and save them to a database. But my IDE (intellij) won't allow me to do so because of the error in the title. Does anyone know a fix to this? Internet research didn't really helped me.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

```
<%
    String name = request.getParameter("realName");
%>
```

Error: Cannot resolve method 'getParameter(java.lang.String)'.

Comment: Please add the relevant code and the error.

Comment: @BheshGurung added the code and the exact error.

Comment: You should not use scriplets in JSP.

Comment: How then? Also, I'm not taking this parameter from the url, I have a form in which the user fills using the post method. All in all I don't think it's really a duplicate question...

Comment: Did you try the suggestion in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1890462/738746? It suggests using EL like `${param.realName}` instead of scriptlet.

Comment: Yes I tried it. But it will not 'resolve the symbol param'.

Comment: What is the version of your IDEA?

Comment: Ultimate 2018.1.4

Comment: Mine is 2017.2.5 and yet it recognizes JSP file and even suggested autocompletion for `param` in EL. Are you sure that it's using JSP editor to open your file?

Comment: How did you write the EL? Just making sure that you didn't put it inside scriptlet `<% ... %>`.

Comment: Yes I did the mistake and put it inside <%... so then what I should do though? it seems that the IDE allows it.

Comment: Do not use `<% ... %>` at all. Just use `${param.realName}` directly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm assuming that your JSP file looks like this:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>$Title$</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <%
    String name = request.getParameter("realName");
  %>
    Here's the param "realName": <%=name%>
  </body>
</html>
```

And that it looks like this, in your IntelliJ:

[image]

If that's the case, I'm almost sure you're missing the `servlet-api.jar` file in your classpath.

Here's one of the ways to add it on IntelliJ:

1. Right-click on your project and select **Open Module Settings**:

[image]

2. Make sure that you're on the **Modules** section, **Dependencies** tab, click on the "+" button at the bottom, and select **1 JARs or directories...**:

[image]

3. Select the file `servlet-api.jar` from the folder `lib` at (THIS IS IMPORTANT:) **the container where you're deploying your application** (in my case, **apache-tomcat-8.5.31**):

[image]

4. Then click on the "Ok" button. Your program now should look like this:

[image]

**You're good to go!**

I hope it helps.

---

*Note: I know that sometimes you cannot avoid to use scriptlets, especially when you're working on legacy codes, as I did for a while. Even though, please also pay attention to the other answers here about using scriptlets. There are several other options available.*

Answer (score 2):

As a complement to the answer, try this on your intellij ide :

1. add support framework
2. check maven
3. go to pom.xml
4. add servlet-api dependency :

   ```
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
       <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
       <version>3.1.0</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```

Comment: +1 for the maven dependency. The key point is the tag "<provided>". You can find more details at https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope Please, pay attention to this one: "This is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime"