# How to retrieve an integer URL parameter with JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-el

What is the correct way in jsp to retrieve a integer parameter from an url?
I need to make sure it's an integer to avoid possible XSS issues, as it's directly inserted in a Spring message i18n and sent to the client.

I need to retrieve 5 from the url `http://localhost?allowed_phones=5`. I've tried this, which does not work:

```
<spring:message code="code" arguments="{Integer.valueOf(param['allowed_phones'])}" />
```

What could be the cause?

Comment: you got an opening brace `{` but no closing brace`}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get parameters from the URL with JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890438/how-to-get-parameters-from-the-url-with-jsp)

Comment: I'm sorry this was a typo in my question, not in my actual code. It's fixed.

Comment: No my main question is basically how to convert the param to an integer.

Comment: @jhamon I've edited my question (and its title) to emphasize that the question is actually about the conversion from String to Integer in JSP.