# How to retrieve parameter values of window.open() in a new jsp page (inside scriptlet)

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, dfc

I've a javascript through which I'm passing some values to a new jsp using window.open()

```
window.open("view.jsp?uname="+objid+"&pass="+ses,"","heightP0 ,widthP0");
```

I want to retrieve the uname and pass values in scriptlet.

I've tried something like this but obviously it's not working and I'm getting null pointer exception.

```
IDfSession session2 = (IDfSession) request.getAttribute("pass"); 
String obj = (String)request.getAttribute("uname");
```

Is it possible to retrieve the values? Also, it is actually passing data from the javascript as I can see the values in the URL. Any idea to how to proceed here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case the uname and pass are passed as request parameters. So to access them in JSP use
<%= request.getParameter("uname") %>
<%= request.getParameter("pass") %>

Comment: That is what I tried but I'm getting null pointer exception.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890438/how-to-get-parameters-from-the-url-with-jsp  Could you please refer this post. Many options are listed there apart from above.